# May a Sumo Rikishi be bald?

Tags: sumo-wrestling

Does the requirement to have a topknot mean that a rikishi who grows sufficiently bald must retire?

Comment: Interesting question... I know of a Yokozuna who had to retire for exactly that reason, but that was almost a century ago.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little late to answer, but [this man](http://sumodb.sumogames.de/Rikishi.aspx?shikona=taikomaru&heya=-1&shusshin=-1&b=-1&high=-1&hd=-1&entry=-1&intai=-1&sort=1) is what you were looking for:

[image]

His name is Taikomaru Yutaka and his retirement ceremony was quite odd: no hair cutting, just some handshaking.